# WINE I can't install programm

Tags: wine

I can't install programm on linux from windows.

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Mariusz, please remember to provide as much information as possible when you ask a question! What program are you trying to install? What's your Ubuntu version? Are you using Wine without a GUI? And it looks like you haven't installed a package called winbind, that's necessary for some Windows applications to work with Wine.

Comment: I'm use Linux Ubuntu 18.04 64bit and use wine without gui. I try install programm Mefisto SMB. After install winbind i have this error       https://ibb.co/cOF6RL

Comment: Are you trying to install the .NET Framework? Wine has its own implementation of that framework, it's called Mono (see it here: [link](https://wiki.winehq.org/Mono) ).